# How do I INSERT to a table with columns that automatically generate values like "createdAt" and "updatedAt"?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to developing APIs with express.js and postgresql.

I'm just trying to INSERT to a table and don't know the appropriate way to do so.

**Request I'm trying to do:**
(I created a column 'dateCreated' before I knew the others were automatically created)

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    models.sequelize.query("INSERT INTO carts ("dateCreated") VALUES (?,?,?)").then(() => {
            console.log("done")
        });
});
```

**PSQL Cart Table**

[image: PSQL output]

**Cart Model:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Cart = sequelize.define("cart", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        dateCreated: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    return Cart;
}
```

**Sequelize setup (index.js):**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('shoptest', 'neymgm', 'password', {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  operatorsAliases: false,
  // logging: true
})

const models = {
  Cart: sequelize.import('./cart'),
  CartItem: sequelize.import('./cartItem'),
  Product: sequelize.import('./product'),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach((modelName) => {
  if ('associate' in models[modelName]) {
    models[modelName].associate(models);
  }
});

models.sequelize = sequelize;
models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = models;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... It will generate `dateCreated` autoimatically

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Cart = sequelize.define("cart", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        }
    }, { dateCreated: 'Created'});
    return Cart;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequelize hooks. There is one for `beforeCreate` which can be used to add/change values before insert. For example;

```
User.beforeCreate((user, options) => {
  return hashPassword(user.password).then(hashedPw => {
    user.password = hashedPw;
  });
});
```

See
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html